# Could not find function or function reference - private function is not found/recognized? Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

If I take some random function from the tview libraty, e.g. kc (Keltner Channel) and save it as my own script, say as kc2, then I can't call it subsequently as part of a strategy Pine Script. It then says: "Could not find function or function reference". I have made sure that the call (capital letters etc. is correct). I can locate the function under My Scripts. So why can't the strategy Pine Script locate the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't just be part of your library, the code for the function needs to actually be included in the strategy script itself.

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay = true)

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Keltner channel section
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

length = input(20, minval=1)
mult = input(1.0, "Multiplier")
src = input(close, title="Source")
exp = input(true, "Use Exponential MA")
BandsStyle = input("Average True Range", options = ["Average True Range", "True Range", "Range"], title="Bands Style")
atrlength = input(10, "ATR Length")
esma(source, length)=>
    s = sma(source, length)
    e = ema(source, length)
    exp ? e : s
ma = esma(src, length)
rangema = BandsStyle == "True Range" ? tr(true) : BandsStyle == "Average True Range" ? atr(atrlength) : rma(high - low, length)
upper = ma + rangema * mult
lower = ma - rangema * mult
u = plot(upper, color=#2962FF, title="Upper")
plot(ma, color=#2962FF, title="Basis")
l = plot(lower, color=#2962FF, title="Lower")
fill(u, l, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 95), title="Background")

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------



// Some other code using KC variables
longSignal = open < ma and close > ma

plotshape(longSignal, location = location.belowbar, style = shape.triangleup, color = color.lime)
```

Comment: I see, do you have a Minimal Working Example? That is how to embed a function into a strategy script

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need to be structured as an actual function. As long as you have the calculations done and the resulting variables available to be referenced by the rest of the script. In the case of KC, you should be able to just copy/paste the built-in's code (not including the version header and the `study()` line) into your new script at the top, and then you can reference `upper`, `lower` etc